# How does evenly spaced X simplify the linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-algebra

What effect does it have on the H-matrix or the regression line?

Comment: 1. Is this for some course/subject? 2. "regression line" implies only a single predictor (one x-variable). Is that your intent?

Comment: This is a question I read from a book. The chapter is about deriving simple linear regression using matrix term. One of the questions given have evenly spaced X and the question ask if this particular characteristic of the data would simplify anything. More specific the X's are: -8, -4, 0, 4, 8 and the question is "What simplifications arose from the spacing of the X levels in the experiment?"

Comment: An example appears in my answer (on another SE site) at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/98223/664.  The formula simplifies greatly.